# node.js server not responding

Tags: node.js

i am trying this simple demo off of the node.js home page:

```
var http = require('http');
http.createServer(function (req, res) {
res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
res.end('Hello World\n');
}).listen(1337, '127.0.0.1');
console.log('Server running at http://127.0.0.1:1337/');
```

i have opened the port on amazon ec2 (1337) in its security group.

```
[root@domU-12-31-38-01-8A-8D servers]# /usr/local/bin/node nodeexample.js
Server running at http://127.0.0.1:1337/
```

i get nothing back but the typical server is not responding. please help this noob out 
danke

Comment: ./node --version         v0.8.9

Comment: How are you trying to send a request off to the server?

Comment: chrome    secure.mathpdq.com:1337

Comment: Try 127.0.0.1 or localhost (on the same machine, of course).

Comment: i want to hit it from afar but i get your point

Comment: Well, you can't do that the way you have it set up - you need to listen on the IP that other computers will see.

Comment: @DrewPierce Then you can't listen to 127.0.0.1, that's only reachable from the local machine.

Comment: i tried that bind but it failed

Comment: if i put in this elastic ip it explodes   54.243.49.108

Comment: @DrewPierce Listen to `0.0.0.0` instead.

Comment: that worked thx   http://secure.mathpdq.com:1337/

Comment: now i will go and find ya'll out there for a few upvotes !

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You're listening to `127.0.0.1` which makes node listen only to the loopback interface and only lets it be be reached *from localhost itself*.

If you listen to `0.0.0.0` instead, you will listen to *all* the machine's network interfaces and lets you be reachable over the Internet on any public IP the machine is using. This is probably what you want.

Comment: Up voted because this problem exists beyond the scope of a node app. This is a really important principle to remember!