# Accessing server from ip address (Node js/Windows)

Tags: node.js

I have a js file with the following code

```
    var http = require('http');
http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
  res.end('Hellosldksldksldk World\n');
}).listen(3000, '127.0.0.1');
console.log('Server running');
```

Now, if I access the server by 127.0.0.1:3000 its perfectly fine, but I want to access it from my own computer ip address. I write 192.xxx.x.xxx:3000, but I cant access it. Since I am developing an android application I need the ip address of the computer in order to run it, can someone explain why I am unable to access it?

Comment: The `127.0.0.0/8` is a loopback address block.

Comment: @Joseph "*Loopback*" means "*this machine*." And, any IP addresses you specify to listen to are the only IP addresses the application can respond to. And, quite simply, `127.0.0.1 != 192.x.x.x`. To respond to requests using multiple IPs, you have to `.listen()` to each of them. Or `.listen()` to [`IPADDR_ANY`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/0.0.0.0) to respond to any IPv4 address by leaving off the `hostname` -- `.listen(3000)`.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/7208062, http://stackoverflow.com/q/13431974, http://stackoverflow.com/q/18678607. Reference: [`server.listen(port, [hostname], ...)`](http://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_server_listen_port_hostname_backlog_callback)

Answer (score 4):

When you say `listen(3000, '127.0.0.1')`, you're explicitly binding your server to port 3000 on IP 127.0.0.1.

You probably just want to bind to all IPs, which you can do by omitting the bind host:

```
listen(3000);
```